# html5 - How to show all required invalid inputs after submit the form

Tags: html, field, required

How can i show, maybe with **red borders**, all invalid required fields (which have `required=""`) when i submit the form. Because by default, is showing one by one.

Comment: You'll have to script it out to do so.

Comment: Sorry. Do you have any ideas to script it ?

Comment: Posted a brief answer as well as a link to a jQuery plugin (something easy to use if you don't have much experience with Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are only getting the first empty field to show "red".

You could do a loop of your form items on submit to check if the are filled out!

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    $( "item" ).each(function( index ) {
         if($(this).val() == "") {
           $( this ).css( "border: thin solid red" );
         }
    });
});
```